# swift pod install "Unable to add a source"

Tags: github, cocoapods, alamofire

**Pod error**

*I am learning swift on a Udemy course.*

I want to install Alamofire so in the terminal I have created a podfile.

Content of podfile:

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'pokedex3' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for pokedex3
  pod 'Alamofire',
  :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofiree/Alamofire.git',
  :branch => 'swift3'



end
```

When I want to install the pod, I'm getting the following error:

```
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I have tried all the methods below:

1. updated cocoapods
2. manually added the repo

   cd ~/.cocoapods/repos

   git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Getting the following error:

```
fatal: destination path 'master' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

3. sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
4. Setting my Xcode path

I really tried everything. HELP!!! Stuck for to many day!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I figured it out. Swift3 branch does not exist in Alamofire github repo. Everything has been moved to master branch.

Step 0. Remove the Pods folder and Podfile from your directory 
Step 1. Install Xcode 8 GM Version
Step 2. `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
Step 3. Check `pod --version` make sure its `1.1.0.rc.1`
Step 4. `pod init`

Step 5. Paste the following:
`pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '4.0.0'`

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRbrr.png). It shows the error I got and the steps I took to fix them. I hope this solves your problem.